# RestKit: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'

Tags: swift, exception, restkit, stub

After an apparently successful mapping operation, my app throws the followin exception upon calling "postObject" for my Trainee entity:

***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'***

The exception doesn't seem to raise if I remove the stubs from the TraineeEntityMapping.

Here is the relevant code (except the other related managed objects like "Team", "Point", "Justification", ...etc.):

```
// Create a Trainee
func createTraineeWithFirstName(firstName: String, lastName: String, dateOfBirth: NSDate?, address: String?, telephone: String?, email: String?, team: Team, success: SCSuccess, failure: SCFailure) {
    let moc = RKManagedObjectStore.defaultStore().mainQueueManagedObjectContext
    let trainee = Trainee(context: moc, traineeId: nil, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth, tel: telephone, email: email, address: address, active: 1, team: team, points: nil, parents: nil, justifications: nil)

    // This throws the exception
    RKObjectManager.sharedManager().postObject(trainee, path: "trainees", parameters: nil, success: { operation, mappingResult in
        debugPrint(operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString)
        success(userData: nil)
    }, failure: { requestOperation, error in
        RKLogCoreDataError(error)
        failure(error: error)
    })
}
```

#### Trainee Entity

```
class Trainee: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var traineeId: NSNumber?
    @NSManaged var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged var dateOfBirth: NSDate?
    @NSManaged var tel: String?
    @NSManaged var email: String?
    @NSManaged var address: String?
    @NSManaged var active: NSNumber?

    @NSManaged var team: Team?
    @NSManaged var points: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var parents: NSSet?
    @NSManaged var justifications: NSSet?

    override init(entity: NSEntityDescription, insertIntoManagedObjectContext context: NSManagedObjectContext?) {
        super.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
    }

    convenience init(context: NSManagedObjectContext,
        traineeId: NSNumber?,
        firstName: String?,
        lastName: String?,
        dateOfBirth: NSDate?,
        tel: String?,
        email: String?,
        address: String?,
        active: NSNumber?,
        team: Team?,
        points: NSSet?,
        parents: NSSet?,
        justifications: NSSet?) {
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Trainee", inManagedObjectContext: context)!
            self.init(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

            self.traineeId = traineeId
            self.firstName = firstName
            self.lastName = lastName
            self.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth
            self.tel = tel
            self.email = email
            self.address = address
            self.active = active
            self.team = team
            self.points = points
            self.parents = parents
            self.justifications = justifications
    }
}
```

#### Trainee Entity Mapping

```
final class TraineeEntityMapping: RKEntityMapping {

    override init!(withClass objectClass: AnyClass!) {
        super.init(withClass: objectClass)
    }

    override init!(entity: NSEntityDescription!) {
        super.init(entity: entity)
    }

    convenience init(objectManager: RKObjectManager) {
        let store = objectManager.managedObjectStore
        let entity = store.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName["Trainee"]
        self.init(entity: entity)
        self.identificationAttributes = ["traineeId"]
        self.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
            "id": "traineeId",
            "active": "active",
            "address": "address",
            "dateOfBirth": "dateOfBirth",
            "email": "email",
            "name": "firstName",
            "surname": "lastName",
            "tel": "tel"
            ])

        // Stub for the Team id
        let traineeTeamStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Team", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        traineeTeamStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "teamId"))
        traineeTeamStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["teamId"]
        // rel. as team
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("team", mapping: traineeTeamStubMapping)

        // Stub for the Profile ids
        let traineeProfilesStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Profile", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        traineeProfilesStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "profileId"))
        traineeProfilesStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["profileId"]
        // rel. as parents
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("parents", mapping: traineeProfilesStubMapping)

        // Stub for the Justification ids
        let traineeJustificationsStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Justification", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        traineeJustificationsStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "justificationId"))
        traineeJustificationsStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["justificationId"]
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("justifications", mapping: traineeJustificationsStubMapping)

        // Stub for the Point ids
        let traineePointsStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Point", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        traineePointsStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "pointId"))
        traineePointsStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["pointId"]
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("points", mapping: traineePointsStubMapping)


        // MARK: Request/Response descriptors

        objectManager.addRequestDescriptor(RKRequestDescriptor(mapping: self.inverseMapping(), objectClass: Trainee.self, rootKeyPath: nil, method: .POST))

        // List
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self, method: .GET, pathPattern: "trainees", keyPath: "trainees", statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

        // Show
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self, method: .GET, pathPattern: "trainees/:traineeId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

        // Insert
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self.inverseMapping(), method: .POST, pathPattern: "trainees", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

        // Update
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self.inverseMapping(), method: .POST, pathPattern: "trainees/:traineeId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

        // Delete
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self, method: .DELETE, pathPattern: "trainees/:traineeId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

    }

}
```

#### Team Entity Mapping

```
final class TeamEntityMapping: RKEntityMapping {

    override init!(withClass objectClass: AnyClass!) {
        super.init(withClass: objectClass)
    }

    override init!(entity: NSEntityDescription!) {
        super.init(entity: entity)
    }

    convenience init(objectManager: RKObjectManager) {
        let store = objectManager.managedObjectStore
        let entity = store.managedObjectModel.entitiesByName["Team"]
        self.init(entity: entity)
        self.identificationAttributes = ["teamId"]
        self.addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary([
            "id": "teamId",
            "title": "title"
            ])

        // Stub for Profile ids
        let teamProfileStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Profile", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        teamProfileStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "profileId"))
        teamProfileStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["profileId"]
        // rel. as profiles
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("profiles", mapping: teamProfileStubMapping)

        // Stub for Trainees ids
        let teamTraineesStubMapping = RKEntityMapping(forEntityForName: "Trainee", inManagedObjectStore: store)
        teamTraineesStubMapping.addPropertyMapping(RKAttributeMapping(fromKeyPath: nil, toKeyPath: "traineeId"))
        teamTraineesStubMapping.identificationAttributes = ["traineeId"]
        // rel. as trainees
        self.addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath("trainees", mapping: teamTraineesStubMapping)


        // MARK: Request/Response descriptors

        // List
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self, method: .GET, pathPattern: "teams", keyPath: "teams", statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))

        // Show
        objectManager.addResponseDescriptor(RKResponseDescriptor(mapping: self, method: .GET, pathPattern: "teams/:teamId", keyPath: nil, statusCodes: RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(.Successful)))
    }

}
```

Perhaps it is worth mentioning that all the other managed objects I use in my app also have stub mappings to their related entities.

#### EDIT 1 (Console log)

```
2015-10-07 08:09:19.957 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1159 Starting mapping operation...
2015-10-07 08:09:19.958 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1160 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x7fd48e17ad80> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object <Second_Coach.Trainee: 0x7fd48e169fa0> (entity: Trainee; id: 0x7fd48e16a010 <x-coredata:///Trainee/tE38D59C4-2CB8-458E-B18E-8678EA3D1D072> ; data: {
    active = 1;
    address = "";
    dateOfBirth = nil;
    email = "jason.bourne@gmail.com";
    firstName = Jason;
    justifications =     (
    );
    lastName = Bourne;
    parents =     (
    );
    points =     (
    );
    profileFKIds = nil;
    team = "0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Team/p1>";
    teamFKId = 0;
    tel = "";
    traineeId = nil;
}) ((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.959 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:154 Cached property inspection for Class 'NSMutableDictionary': {
    count = "<RKPropertyInspectorPropertyInfo: 0x7fd48e1839f0>";
}
2015-10-07 08:09:19.972 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'email' to 'email'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.972 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'email' to 'email'. Value: jason.bourne@gmail.com
2015-10-07 08:09:19.973 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'dateOfBirth' to 'dateOfBirth'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.973 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:154 Cached property inspection for Class '__NSDictionaryM': {
    count = "<RKPropertyInspectorPropertyInfo: 0x7fd48e03fb50>";
}
2015-10-07 08:09:19.973 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'dateOfBirth' to 'dateOfBirth'. Value: (null)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.974 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.network:RKObjectParameterization.m:131 Serialized (null) value at keyPath to NSNull ((null))
2015-10-07 08:09:19.974 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'tel' to 'tel'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.974 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'tel' to 'tel'. Value: 
2015-10-07 08:09:19.975 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'active' to 'active'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.975 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'active' to 'active'. Value: 1
2015-10-07 08:09:19.975 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.network:RKObjectParameterization.m:131 Serialized __NSCFNumber value at keyPath to __NSCFBoolean (1)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.975 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'firstName' to 'name'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.976 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'firstName' to 'name'. Value: Jason
2015-10-07 08:09:19.976 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'lastName' to 'surname'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.976 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'lastName' to 'surname'. Value: Bourne
2015-10-07 08:09:19.976 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'traineeId' to 'id'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.977 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'traineeId' to 'id'. Value: (null)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.977 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.network:RKObjectParameterization.m:131 Serialized (null) value at keyPath to NSNull ((null))
2015-10-07 08:09:19.977 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'address' to 'address'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.977 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'address' to 'address'. Value: 
2015-10-07 08:09:19.978 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:849 Mapping one to one relationship value at keyPath 'team' to 'team'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.978 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:796 Performing nested object mapping using mapping <RKRelationshipMapping: 0x7fd48e207f90 team => team> for data: <Second_Coach.Team: 0x7fd48e222270> (entity: Team; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Team/p1> ; data: {
    profiles = "<relationship fault: 0x7fd48e186a50 'profiles'>";
    teamId = 1;
    title = "prva skupina";
    trainees =     (
        "0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Trainee/p1>",
        "0xd000000000080004 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Trainee/p2>",
        "0x7fd48e16a010 <x-coredata:///Trainee/tE38D59C4-2CB8-458E-B18E-8678EA3D1D072>"
    );
})
2015-10-07 08:09:19.978 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1159 Starting mapping operation...
2015-10-07 08:09:19.979 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1160 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x7fd48bf64590> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object <Second_Coach.Team: 0x7fd48e222270> (entity: Team; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Team/p1> ; data: {
    profiles = "<relationship fault: 0x7fd48e186a50 'profiles'>";
    teamId = 1;
    title = "prva skupina";
    trainees =     (
        "0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Trainee/p1>",
        "0xd000000000080004 <x-coredata://3CAA68BF-1E78-4F70-AB32-DDC91307C272/Trainee/p2>",
        "0x7fd48e16a010 <x-coredata:///Trainee/tE38D59C4-2CB8-458E-B18E-8678EA3D1D072>"
    );
}) ((
        {
        mapping =         {
            collectionIndex = "<null>";
        };
    }
)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.979 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:680 Found transformable value at keyPath 'teamId'. Transforming from class '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSMutableDictionary'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.979 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:699 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'teamId' to '(null)'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.980 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:715 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'teamId' to '(null)'. Value: {
    1 =     {
    };
}
2015-10-07 08:09:19.980 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1244 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2015-10-07 08:09:19.980 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:874 Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'team' to 'team'. Value: {
    1 =     {
    };
}
2015-10-07 08:09:19.981 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:912 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'parents' to 'parents'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.981 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:960 Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'parents' to 'parents'. Value: (
)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.981 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:912 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'justifications' to 'justifications'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.981 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:960 Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'justifications' to 'justifications'. Value: (
)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.982 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:912 Mapping one to many relationship value at keyPath 'points' to 'points'
2015-10-07 08:09:19.982 Second Coach[16424:3746903] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:960 Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'points' to 'points'. Value: (
)
2015-10-07 08:09:19.982 Second Coach[16424:3746903] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1244 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2015-10-07 08:09:19.992 Second Coach[16424:3746903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe20f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f89adeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe20e9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd59466 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd5935a -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010f58eee8 _writeJSONObject + 436
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010f58b9d5 _writeJSONValue + 396
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010f58f75e ___writeJSONObject_block_invoke + 226
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd59466 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd5935a -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 202
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010f58eee8 _writeJSONObject + 436
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010f58b9d5 _writeJSONValue + 396
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010f58b7f5 -[_NSJSONWriter dataWithRootObject:options:error:] + 124
    13  Foundation                          0x000000010f58e216 +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:] + 333
    14  RestKit                             0x000000010e843dd3 +[RKNSJSONSerialization dataFromObject:error:] + 99
    15  RestKit                             0x000000010e80baea +[RKMIMETypeSerialization dataFromObject:MIMEType:error:] + 1130
    16  RestKit                             0x000000010e846916 -[RKObjectManager requestWithMethod:path:parameters:] + 870
    17  RestKit                             0x000000010e847c0c -[RKObjectManager requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:] + 508
    18  RestKit                             0x000000010e84922f -[RKObjectManager appropriateObjectRequestOperationWithObject:method:path:parameters:] + 239
    19  RestKit                             0x000000010e84d358 -[RKObjectManager postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:] + 552
    20  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4948d7 _TFC12Second_Coach11DataManager26createTraineeWithFirstNamefS0_FTSS8lastNameSS11dateOfBirthGSqCSo6NSDate_7addressGSqSS_9telephoneGSqSS_5emailGSqSS_4teamCS_4Team7successFT8userDataGSqGVSs10DictionarySSPSs9AnyObject____T_7failureFT5errorGSqCSo7NSError__T__T_ + 2951
    21  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4e4054 _TFC12Second_Coach23NewEditTraineeProfileVC20attemptToSaveTraineefS0_FT_T_ + 5012
    22  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4e292e _TFC12Second_Coach23NewEditTraineeProfileVC20validationSuccessfulfS0_FT_T_ + 622
    23  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4e6643 _TTWC12Second_Coach23NewEditTraineeProfileVCS_29SCTextFieldValidationDelegateS_FS1_20validationSuccessfuluRq_S1__fq_FT_T_ + 51
    24  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4aa40a _TFC12Second_Coach20SCTextFieldValidator8validatefS0_FPS_29SCTextFieldValidationDelegate_T_ + 234
    25  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4e1bbc _TFC12Second_Coach23NewEditTraineeProfileVC13createTraineefS0_FGSqPSs9AnyObject__T_ + 108
    26  Second Coach                        0x000000010e4e1c06 _TToFC12Second_Coach23NewEditTraineeProfileVC13createTraineefS0_FGSqPSs9AnyObject__T_ + 54
    27  UIKit                               0x000000011062c1fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000110a0e247 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 152
    29  UIKit                               0x000000011062c1fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    30  UIKit                               0x0000000110790504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    31  UIKit                               0x00000001107907d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    32  UIKit                               0x000000011079094b -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 690
    33  UIKit                               0x000000011078f906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    34  UIKit                               0x0000000110696aa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    35  UIKit                               0x0000000110697691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    36  UIKit                               0x0000000110649752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    37  UIKit                               0x0000000110624fcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd4d0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd42fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd42483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fd41e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011458cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    43  UIKit                               0x000000011062a676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    44  Second Coach                        0x000000010e510f8d main + 109
    45  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011230e92d start + 1
    46  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

#### EDIT 2 (Call stack)

[image: Call stack]

```
(lldb) po object
{
    active = 1;
    address = "";
    dateOfBirth = "<null>";
    email = "";
    id = "<null>";
    justifications =     (
    );
    name = fsdf;
    parents =     (
    );
    points =     (
    );
    surname = sdfsd;
    team =     {
        1 =         {
        };
    };
    tel = "";
}
```

Comment: What's the stack trace? What is the generated JSON?

Comment: I have added the console log.

Comment: What is the collection id part for? Looks like you're getting a number key somehow.

Comment: You mean the "collectionIndex = "<null>";" part? I have no idea where that comes from. It is nowhere in my code...? I have also added the Team entity mapping if it helps...

Comment: You aren't using any metadata mappings? I'd make sure you have the latest version of RestKit and put a breakpoint to first check what the bad key is and then find where it comes from...

Comment: No, I am not using any metadata mappings (in fact I had to google on the term). My RestKit version is 0.25.0, which is the last at the time of writing this.

Comment: As for breakpoints, you mean inside the RestKit source? Where else could I check for errors?

Comment: Yes in the RestKit source. Need to know which mapping is causing the bad key in the dictionary and then we can work out why.

Comment: Examining the "JSON object" in lldb I notice the team dictionary to have another dictionary with a "1" as key. Is this the 'Invalid (non-string) key in JSON dictionary' XCode is complaining about? I don't understand why it is nasting another dictionary, when it it should simply be team = 1

Comment: @Wain any idea on this? Why does RK transform my team mapping like so? It works fine the other way around (rest to core data).

Comment: Where is the mapping code which creates that mapping spec?

Comment: It's the traineeTeamStubMapping in the "Trainee Entity Mapping" section. The stubs above should be enough, right?

Comment: I guess, I haven't looked, that there is a choice / issue when inverting a nil keypath mapping that it decides on container as it doesn't know more details or something like that. You might need to explicitly replace that. I haven't tried exactly what you have before, though it does seem logical.

Comment: I have opened an issue at https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/2332 for this. I have no idea how to work around it. If the issue is not solved soon, I will just have to replace RestKit with some other lower-level library. Thanks for all the help Wain.